# NestJs GraphQL playground access

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I can't seem to access the GraphQL Playground using NestJS. I'm exploring the documentation and have followed this https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start up to the Resolvers section to generate the `schema.gql`, but attempting to reach `localhost:3000/graphql` is not able to connect.

At first I thought my code was setup incorrectly, but I spent some time digging into Nest's examples and found that those also do not work when trying to access the `/graphql` endpoint. It does work if I setup a `get` endpoint to return a JSON body using the REST method.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { RecipesModule } from './recipes/recipes.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    RecipesModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is directly from the NestJS example. My understanding is that the GraphQLModule should be setting up the connection to the `/graphql` endpoint. Following the docs, `graphql, apollo-server-express, and graphql-tools` were all installed.

Any idea why the graphql route is not connecting?

[Edit]:
Things I've tried so far:

- setting `playground: true` explicitly with GraphQLModule.forRoot
- verified `NODE_ENV` is not 'production'
- confirmed server works when creating resolvers using REST
- curl'd `localhost:3000/graphql` and receive a graphql validation error, so confirm that connects correctly

Comment: Check what your `process.env.NODE_ENV` is. If it is `PRODUCTION` then I think `apollo-server` disables the playground. If not, try adding `playground: true` explicitly

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I should've specified what I've tried already on the post, sorry. I've tried both and unfortunately, wasn't able to connect to the endpoint. I just curl'ed the endpoint to see if it is connecting to graphql and seems like it is since it returns GraphQL validation errors.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproduction then? Can't see from what you've shared why that would be happening

Comment: So, I've tried with nest's example in their github repo (https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/23-graphql-code-first). It's about as basic as it can get and is essentially the same as the documentation's example. Nothing modified, just unable to connect to gql playground. Same result curling, able to see the gql validation errors, so it's connecting on the server though.

Comment: With that sample, the curl fails, but a browser requests to the same location succeeds. Probably looking at the user agent. It doesn't make much sense to send an interactive playground to the command line

Comment: Of course, for the command line I was just referring to sending a Post request to run a query, not trying to access the playground. But those requests worked and the queries in the schema were correctly being referenced. Odd that playground was accessible to you but not on my end, will dig a bit more and see if I figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with WSL2 running on Windows 10. This thread on github has some insight into the issue.

Disable Fast Startup to allow access to localhost.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5298

Answer (score 10):

sometimes `helmet` causes this same issue. if you have helmet loaded as a middleware, it might probably also cause this.

Comment: disabling helmet solves the issue in NestJs, but I'm wondering what causes it? And if that is the problem is that an option to disable helmet in the dev mode?

Comment: Helmet was a problem in my case too

Comment: does anybody know why helmet cause this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue this is what I did. I hope you will find it helpful. I appreciated everyone's support.

Step1:
// app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      // autoSchemaFile: true,    did not work!
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      // schema.gql will automatically be created
      debug: true,
      playground: true,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppResolver],   // all resolvers & service should be in providers
```

step 2:

> Make sure you have one at least query bcz Mutation is not enough if you don't GraphQL playground will not start. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64106012/7522931)

Answer (score 1):

2 years late but found a simple workaround, since helmet was the issue too.
Conditionally use `helmet()`, like this:

```
process.env.CURRENT_ENV === 'dev' && app.use(helmet())
```

Assuming `CURRENT_ENV` is a custom environment variable that I use instead of `NODE_ENV`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dist folder and restarting the app worked for me.